# how to force a div to expand to its content?

Tags: css

although my questions has been answered lots of times before, but all the proposed solution I have tried and nothing seems to work.

- what am trying to do is a big div that contains li tags; the li tags will also contain anchor tag, 2 divs and p tag.
- to understand the big picture.. am trying to make a posting wall (activity-board), the wall will have posts looks like a bubble (div post) and the bubble will point (post-arrow) to a thumbnail image (a thumb3), to make the bubble style I made the post div absolute positioned with z-index less than the arrow-post.
- and here is my css:

  ```
  .activity-board {

  background:#fff;
  width:600px;
  min-height:652px;
  height:auto;
  border:solid 2px #e7d28d;
  border-radius: 6px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 6px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
   float:left;
   margin-left:20px;

   }

     .post-body{
      position:relative;
      display:block;
      list-style-type:none;
      width:600px;
      height:auto;
      background:#f9f9f9;
      border-bottom:1px solid #CBCBCB;
      border-radius:4px 4px 0 0; 
      -moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0; 
          -webkit-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
      background: #fff;
      float:left;
      overflow:visible;
      clear:both;
      z-index:9;
      }

  .post{

  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  line-height:20px;
  height:auto;
  background:#FFF;
  display:block;
  margin-top:22.5px;
  margin-left:77px;
  text-align:left;
  float:left;
  z-index:1;

  }

  .post-arrow{

   position:relative;
   margin-top:32px;
   margin-left:6px;
   width:12px;
   height:18px;
   background:url(images/post-arrow.png);
   float:left;
   z-index:5;

   }

  .post p{ color:#025373; padding:8px; word-wrap:break-word; }

  a.thumb-3 { 

  margin-top:18px;
  display:block;
  margin-left:18px;
  width:46px;
  height:46px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  z-index:10;
  float:left;

  }


  a.thumb-3 img{

  padding:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:46px;
  height:46px;
  float:left;
  border-radius:3px; 
  -moz-border-radius:3px; 
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;

  }
  ```
- here is my html:

  ```
  <ul>
   <li class="post-body">
        <a class="thumb-3"><img src="images/Alsheikh Center (177).jpg" /></a>
        <div class="post-arrow"></div>

        <div class="post">
          <p>
          Hi there!
          </p>

       </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
  ```

http://jsfiddle.net/r9YpX/

Everything worked fine but the li tag does not expand to the content.. it only expands if I change the position of the post div to relative not absolute, which I cant change because it must be absolutely positioned under the arrow image to give it the bubble look.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot flow content around absolutely-positioned elements. It would help if you had a fiddle with images showing. http://jsfiddle.net/r9YpX/

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r9YpX/1

Comment: sorry I tried to upload images but I can because am less than 10 points reputation :)

Comment: ill use fiddle thanks

Comment: There are other ways to position your elements as you like besides using absolute. I suggest trying that.

Comment: execuse but how to upload images to fiddle, sorry am new to this

Comment: could you please explain how to use other ways for positioning.

Comment: ok Thanks guys i figuered it out.. I made position:relative and changed margin for post div and it worked! I thought I did this but perhaps I did something wrong that make it not work

Comment: You can upload images to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok Thanks guys i figuered it out.. I made position:relative and changed margin for post div and it worked! I thought I did this but perhaps I did something wrong that make it not work